# vim-go completion stopped working after updating

Tags: go, neovim, coc.nvim

I'm using neovim with [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) and have been using [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) and [coc-go](https://github.com/josa42/coc-go), and everything was working fine.

I have the habit of updating everything every couple of days, and I do that using the following commands:

```
:PlugUpgrade
:PlugUpdate
:GoUpdateBinaries
:CocUpdateSync
```

Recently after I did the update, the auto-completion for `go` files has stopped working.

Things I tried:

- I thought there might be a conflict with `coc-go`, so I tried uninstalling it, but it didn't solve the issue
- On my other computer, I opened a `go` file before and after running the update (without changing anything else), and auto-completion stopped working after the update
- I tried cleaning up `mod` and `bin` directories in my `GOPATH`, and reinstalling everything, but still, it's not working.

When I open a `go` file, I see the message `vim-go: initialized gopls`, but I also see the following message

```
[coc.nvim]: Unhandled rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'workspaceFolders' of undefined
```

I thought this message is responsible for things being broken, but that's not the case: after digging a bit on the message, that message is coming from `coc-go`, but even when I uninstall `coc-go`, my auto-completion is still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This change helped me to fix the error -> https://github.com/josa42/coc-go/pull/89/commits/046eb6f8d2686b2317e15d58535435592b1eaa76

Find the `extension.js` file in coc's config folder. In my case, it is located in `"$HOME/config/coc/extensions/node_modules/coc-go/lib"` and replace these lines:

```
disableWorkspaceFolders: config.disable.workspaceFolders,
disableDiagnostics: config.disable.diagnostics,
disableCompletion: config.disable.completion,
```

with:

```
disableWorkspaceFolders: config.disableWorkspaceFolders,
disableDiagnostics: config.disableDiagnostics,
disableCompletion: config.disableCompletion,
```

Comment: Thank you @Genjik, that seems to do the trick. Although it's confusing for me; I tried taking `coc-go` out of the question by uninstalling it, by I was still facing the issue, so I was sure it's something in `vim-go`. In fact, I was just in the process of creating an issue in there, and I thought: "OK, let me check one last time on SO to see if there's an answer"!!!

Comment: @Farzad, that is weird. Did you restart the vim/neovim after :CocUninstall coc-go?

Comment: I did @Genjik, and that's, as you mentioned, super confusing. I don't know what was wrong there